# subscribe error on http request passing firebase token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, observable, subscribe

Trying to pass a firebase token to a nodejs api and retrieve data. I'm getting a subscribe error : TSS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void.
The user profile data is stored in a mongoDB collection, which is accessible via the api

This code in my user service works

```
 public getCurrUser() {
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + '/userinfo').pipe(map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      const userinfo = res;
      console.log('user docs: ', userinfo);
      return userinfo;
    }));

  }
```

Here is the code in the service, wrapped with passing the user token:

```
    getUserData() {
        const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
          .then(authToken => {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': authToken });
            return this.http.get(baseUrl + '/userinfo', {headers}).pipe(map((res) => {
              console.log('the results of getUserData : ', res);
              const userinfo = res;
              console.log('logged in user info: ', userinfo);

              return userinfo;
            }));
          });
    }
```

This is the code that is not compiling with the subscribe error, which is calling the service from the component page:

```
    public getCurrUserData() {

        this.userCurr = null;

        console.log('in user admin component - retrieval of curr user')
        this.userAdminService.getUserData()
          .subscribe(
            (userCurr: UserProfileModel[]) => {
              this.userCurr = userCurr;
              console.log('loading current user: ', this.userCurr);
            }

          );

      }
```

It seems to be related to returning an observable, but I can't put my finger on the fix. Any hep would be appreciated

Comment: Of what type is your userAdminService.getUserData()? You can check by moving the mouse over it when you use vscode.

Comment: It looks like you just forgot to add return statement to `getUserData()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUserData()` is not returning an observable right away to which you can subscribe and Hence the error. It has a promise first which when resolved than return an observable but `this.userAdminService.getUserData().subscribe()` expects an observable returned by `getUserData()`.

You can either try and convert you observables to promises losing real time changes or maybe you can do something like this :

```
getUserData(authToken) {
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': authToken });
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + '/userinfo', {headers}).pipe(map((res) => {
        console.log('the results of getUserData : ', res);
        const userinfo = res;
        console.log('logged in user info: ', userinfo);

        return userinfo;
    }));
}

public getCurrUserData() {
    this.userCurr = null;

    console.log('in user admin component - retrieval of curr user');
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
        .then(authToken => {    
            this.userAdminService.getUserData(authToken )
            .subscribe((userCurr: UserProfileModel[]) => {
                this.userCurr = userCurr;
                console.log('loading current user: ', this.userCurr);
            }
        );
    });
}
```